# Number of pairings up to cyclic permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let us have a set of $2n$ elements and a cyclic permutation on this set. What is the number of pairings of elements of this set up to this permutation?

I am not sure if this question is too easy for MathOverflow (or, as it sometimes happens with such combinatorial problems, hard enough), but I did not manage to find the answer by myself.

Edit: I will try to clarify the question. Let our set be the set $\{1,...,2n\}$ and the permutation be just the cyclic permutation $\sigma = (1~2~... ~2n)$. Then pairings $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},...,\{2n-1,2n\}\}$ and $\{\{2,3\},\{4,5\},...,\{2n,1\}\}$ are equivalent as we can receive one as the image of the other by the permutation $\sigma$ (or its powers). The problem is that the number of elements in equivalence classes is quite different (as an example, $[\{1,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,6\}]= \{\{1,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,6\}\}$ and $[\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{5,6\}]$ consists of 6 different pairings).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear to me. Can you give some examples to help explain what you mean?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Yes, of course. The easy subproblem is to find just the number of pairings of a set with $2n$ elements. It is equal to $(2n-1)!!$. But what if I consider two pairings equivalent if one can be transformed in the other by a fixed cyclic permutation. Thank you for the commentary, I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Questions like this are dealt with in the theory of enumerating combinatorial structures up to a given permutation group developed by Polya, see. e.g. here: https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Huisinga.pdf

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta Thank you, I will investigate this article.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007769

Comment: @MartinRubey This completely answers the question. Thank you very much, I will write an answer myself as soon as I fully understand the more or less explicit formula.